# How to use external toolchain with yocto

Tags: yocto, toolchain

I wanted to use my platform toolchain before.
but changing toolchain isn't easy for me.
I don't know external toolchain is allowed by yocto
How can I do?

Thank you so much

step:

1. clone poky and meta-external-toolchain
2. clone https://github.com/BPI-SINOVOIP/BPI-W2-bsp.git to /tmp
3. modify/add conf/local.conf
   3.1 modify MACHINE ??= "qemux86" to MACHINE ??= "qemuarm64"
   3.2 add EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/tmp/BPI-W2-bsp/toolchains/asdk64-4.9.4-a53-EL-3.10-g2.19-a64nt-160307"
4. add meta-external-toolchain path to conf/bblayers.conf
5. run bitbake xz -e | grep CC=

I got the messages

```
export CC="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/tmp/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/xz/5.2.4-r0/recipe-sysroot"
```

but I want to use this gcc to build packages

```
/tmp/BPI-W2-bsp/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

How can I modify it??

Answer (score 1):

External Toolchain is supported in yocto. you can do this by setting value to `TCMODE` & `EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN` variable (Ref [Yocto ref-manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-TCMODE)). Find more information for setting external toolchain from this [meta-sourcery](https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/meta-sourcery/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a meta (http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/meta-external-toolchain/) from poky. 
I try to set EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/tmp/BPI-W2-bsp/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu" in the local.conf, but it's not successful.

toolchain source: https://github.com/BPI-SINOVOIP/BPI-W2-bsp/tree/master/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu